# MYSQL startup and needed requirements

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm new to mySQL and cannot install XAMPP due to laptop restrictions, anyone has ideas to have a localhost and Apatchi and other needed requirements to start MYSQL/PHP learning? on my PC without having to install this program?

Comment: What restrictions? Can you not install anything or is it just XAMPP that it does not allow

Comment: What on earth has the TAG "Character Encoding" got to do with anything in the question?

Comment: PHP manual has guidance on installing php with apache: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php Mysql also has guidance how to install it on a computer on its own website.

Comment: Cannot install any program, also I got lost in the php manual guide

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have administrator permissions on your laptop, you may use a vm to learn MySQL.

One of the easiest ways could be using e.g. DigitalOcean with a start credit (for free) or any other provider and start with a small vm. https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/mysql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).